# Need advice on designing a system

Tags: javascript, mysql, performance

I'm trying to design a page to make it work the fastest while also trying to avoid duplication.

Basically, I'm going to load 3 sets of a user's contacts. Business contacts, personal contacts, and special contacts, which could be a mixture of both business/personal. So in essence I'd be doing these 3 queries:

```
SELECT stuff FROM contacts WHERE userId = '$userId' AND type = 'business'

SELECT stuff FROM contacts WHERE userId = '$userId' AND type = 'personal'

SELECT stuff FROM contacts WHERE userId = '$userId' and isSpecial = 1
```

These contacts will be used by javascript to populate certain `<div>s` on the page and be used in searching the contacts on the page.

Would it make more sense to load only the business and personal contacts, then loop through them via javascript and use javascript to build the 3rd list of special contacts, essentially where `isSpecial` is set to 1?

Or would it be better to get the 3 sets seperately using a MySQL query and pass them on to javascript as 3 seperate sets from the get go?

Or should I only get 1 set of contacts from MySQL as long as `userId = '$currentUser'` and sort them into seperate lists via javascript when the page loads? (I will be looping through all contacts on the page load anyway to populate their respective `<div>`s, perhaps I could also sort them into 3 seperate lists while I'm looping through them?)

Or would any other approach be the best?

My concern here is to make everything as fast as possible for the user, while also minimizing the strain on the database server.

Comment: I recommend one big list and rendering based on data binding (maybe knockout?)

Comment: @Raynos what do those terms mean? (data binding and knockout )

Comment: [knockoutjs](http://knockoutjs.com/) A library for data binding data to the DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO it's be better if you use MySQL itself to get the contacts separately as MySQL is comparatively faster.  Also just in case if javascript is turned off in the users browser, or if he is using mobile browser, then you'll not be able to segregate the contacts.

**EDIT**

As you has pointed out, javascript is a minimum requisite for your site, then the best way would be to use a single  go with a single query to get the data and segregate using js.

Comment: The mobile browsers thing isn't a concern because this page is heavily built on javascript, if someone has it disabled then its not supported by us.

Answer (score 1):

Do only one query, load both "business" and "personal" in that query, and then find the "isSpecial" ones afterwards. (That assumes that there's not some other type to worry about.)

Comment: Any reasons why to do it this way?

Answer (score 1):

Can you not do:

SELECT stuff FROM contacts WHERE userId = '$userId' AND type = 'business' OR type = 'personal' OR isSpecial = 1

Then you only have one call into the database.

You can also change SELECT stuff to only select the fields you need.  In addition, change your sql query to get the database to sort the contacts as you require.

Update
OK, just an idea, on page load you do SELECT for first eg 20 contacts (up to) then run javascript to display them or whatever, then when you receive event that page has fully loaded, you then do SELECT statement for remaining rows (if there are any).

Comment: He wants to display them separately. So the problem is not only fetching but also segregating them according to type.

Comment: I can do that but I'm concerned about how long the user would have to wait when I'm sorting them through into seperate lists via javscript on page load. (There could be 100-200 contacts for both business & personal)